# Convert PDF to image

Tags: image, pdf

I use this command in my shell to convert from PDF to image

```
convert -density 150x150 <PDF filename> -append -quality 100 <Image filename>
```

The PDF has four pages, but I only need the last two. How can I remove the first two pages from the PDF and convert the ones which remain to an image?

Comment: This is not a php question. You should find the documentation of this convert tool, whatever it may be.

Comment: @GolezTrol: Agreed. It's like writing the code `$a = 5 + 2;` and expecting the result `8`, then tagging it PHP because you happened to run into your mathematical misunderstanding whilst writing PHP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you are using ImageMagick in combination with GhostScript. You can specify the page number of the PDF like this:

```
convert -density 150x150 <PDF filename>[0] -append -quality 100 <Image filename>
```

where **0** is the page number minus 1 (indexing starts at 0).

In your special case it would be

```
convert -density 150x150 <PDF filename>[2] <PDF filename>[3] -append -quality 100 <Image filename>
```