# PDF to image for mobile device?

Tags: image, pdf, smartphone

I have PDF files that I want to send to smart phones as jpg's, but I want to preserve images, text formatting, etc.  I found some tools for converting PDF's to imagese, but most of these won't render it first to be readable on a smart phone.  The one I found that will convert a PDF to an image suitable for a smart phone (eBook to Images) uses character recognition and rewrites the PDF (you lose any images or formatting).  Is there a way I can convert a PDF to an image meant to be viewed on a mobile device?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use Ghostscript, which is available under GPL and works on a wide range of platforms. You could also use MuPDF which again is available GPL and therefore as source. MuPDF also works on a variety of platforms, including some smart phones. I too am part of the development teams for these products.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use Windows box for the file conversion, using [Amyuni PDF Creator](http://www.amyuni.com/en/developer/pdfcreator/features.html) you can export a PDF file as a jpg image and specify the resolution (in DPI) you want to use for your images.

C# Example:

```cs
System.IO.FileStream testfile = new System.IO.FileStream("TestFile.pdf",FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read,FileShare.Read);
string exportedFile = "JpegExport.jpg";
IacDocument document = new IacDocument( null );
//Open a pdf document
document.Open(testfile,"");
//Export it to Jpeg
//ExportToJPeg(exportedFile, 300 /*resolution*/, 7 /*compression level*/, 1 /*start page*/, 2 /*end  page*/);
document.ExportToJPeg(exportedFile, 300, 7, 1, 2);
```

The main reason for using DPI resolution is that you can have pages with different size inside a single PDF file, specifing the export resolution in DPI preserves the size relation between pages in the resulting images.
You can download the trial version and test it with your files to see if it fits for your needs.

*Disclaimer: I am part of the development team for this product*
Similiar questions in SO:

[Rasterize PDF's with font not embedded using GhostScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6643817/rasterize-pdfs-with-font-not-embedded-using-ghostscript/6682165#6682165)
[PDF to image using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886042/pdf-to-image-using-java)
[Converting PDF to images automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002055/converting-pdf-to-images-automatically)
[Convert PDF to image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294391/convert-pdf-to-image)
[Best way to convert pdf files to tiff files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75500/best-way-to-convert-pdf-files-to-tiff-files)

Comment: You could use Ghostscript, which is available under GPL and works on a wide range of platforms. You could also use MuPDF which again is available GPL and therefore as source. MuPDF also works on a variety of platforms, including some smart phones. I too am part of the development teams for these products.